# bootstrap multiselect not working on api json bind in Ajax call in jquery

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I am trying to use Bootstrap multiselect checkbox in my page. if the data to it is static, it is working fine without problem. but if i dynamically bind json data to it, the drop down is not working.

This is my HTML :

```
<select id="categories" ></select>
```

And this is loading when DOM is ready :

```
var categCheck  = $('#categories').multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
     enableFiltering : true
});
```

Here is the API call through ajax, where i am getting data from it.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/api/categoryapi',
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
            var opt = $('<option />', {
                value: item._id,
                text: item.title
            });
            opt.appendTo(categCheck);
            categCheck.multiselect('refresh');
        });
    }
});
```

When I try to pull down the drop down box, it is not working, I couldn't find out the problem. Am I doing any mistake here ? Even I have added all supporting files which is required for multi select box in the html page.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `'refresh'`:

```js
categCheck.multiselect('refresh');
```

I have tried `'rebuild'`:

```js
categCheck.multiselect('rebuild');
```

This works fine!